# How to add tab in ribbon in excel add in using asp.net c#

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins, office-2016, excel-online

We're trying to build a Custom Excel Add-in that runs on Office installation as well as Office 365. We're trying to add a custom tab to the Ribbon for the add-in. From the tutorials studied, I understand that we can add a task pane to custom Excel Add-ins. I have written the below code to add a Custom tab to the ribbon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
          xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
          xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

  <Id>52dc8a93-3686-4ea3-8e2e-2bc92714f908</Id>

  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="TTSTurbo" />
  <Description DefaultValue="TTSTurbo"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png" />

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.contoso.com" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Home.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>

            <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />

          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="Contoso.Group1">
                <Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label" />
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>

                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
            <CustomTab id="Contoso.TabCustom">
              <Group id="Contoso.TabCustom2.group2">
                <Label resid="residCustomTabGroupLabel"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="blue-icon-16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="blue-icon-80" />
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Button2">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <OfficeControl id="Superscript" />
              </Group>
              <Label resid="customTabLabel1" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button16x16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button80x80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Home.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Group1Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

However, when I am publishing the .xml file to see the add-in, I do not see the custom tab on the ribbon. Pls advise on what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: What did you try? What isn't working?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers updated the question with code n output, hope this helps

Comment: You should likely just put in your whole manifest TBH.

Comment: What is you Dev environment? Office Online or Deskto? Are you using VSCode or VStudio? NPM Webserver? HTTPS? Can you load the xml without the custom group.

Comment: I am using office online and visual studio 2022 excel web add in. Not using NPM webserver

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Updated the question with mainfest.xml code

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/customtab?view=common-js-preview) regarding the usage of defining a CustomTab element in the manifest. You can define [groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/group?view=common-js-preview) of [controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/control?view=common-js-preview)(the custom button you refered to) in the CustomTab.

Comment: @SouravDas could you elaborate a bit about the error you had?

Comment: This is a link only answer to a poorly written question.

Comment: @zhenhuangMSFT I have modified the question with the code written but somehow the published .xml file is neither giving any error nor adding any customtab. Can you pls help?